# Spring Boot properties file externalization

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-boot, maven-profiles

I currently have 3 properties files:
**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

**application-develoment.properties**

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
db.username=user
db.password=pswd

#Data source management:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

**application-production.properties**

```
#DB properties:
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myproddb
db.username=admin
db.password=admin

#Data source management:
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
```

I have my maven profiles set as follows in my **pom.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>development</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>production</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>production</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and my DataSourceConfig's: annotaion **@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")**

Everything works fine when I compile with development or production profile, but now I want to externalize the properties files to the /conf/localhost directory of my Tomcat server, any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Just put the application-*.properties files where your .jar is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring Cloud Config server to give you a centralised, externalised configuration (and a lot more besides).

https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

You can pass new configuration files

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/new.properties,file:/home/override.properties
```

this will override configuration defined in configuration file inside the jar.